How can i implement a triple aes encryption to make dpa attack last a little longer on my case study?
I am trying to implement tmr methodology for my AES operation and i want to do it with the same key and the same plaintext slightly changed randomly for the last two plaintexts. I also added a voter and my goal is for my DPA attack to take a little longer to break it but it takes around the same time. Any thoughts?
(i made the changes on my main script and not aess.cpp)
i tried this:
    #include "mbed.h"

#include "aes.h"
#include "time.h"
// Create a DigitalOutput object to toggle an LED whenever data is received.
static DigitalOut led(LED1);

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

int main(void)
{

    uint8_t key[] = { 0xfc, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x2d, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
    char plaintext1[16], plaintext2[16], plaintext3[16];
    
    uint8_t ciphertext1[16], ciphertext2[16], ciphertext3[16], ciphertext[16];

    pc.baud(115200);

    while (1) {

        //pc.gets(plaintext,16);

                // Print on serial
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){

           plaintext1[i] = pc.getc();
           plaintext2[i] = (plaintext1[i])/2;
           plaintext3[i] = (plaintext1[i]);
    
        }
       

        
        // Encrypt the received data 
        AES_ECB_encrypt((uint8_t*)plaintext1, key, ciphertext1, 16);
        wait_us(1);
        AES_ECB_encrypt((uint8_t*)plaintext2, key, ciphertext2, 16);
        wait_us(1);
        AES_ECB_encrypt((uint8_t*)plaintext3, key, ciphertext3, 16);



        // Print on serial
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (ciphertext1[i] == ciphertext2[i] || ciphertext1[i] == ciphertext3[i]) {
                ciphertext[i] = ciphertext1[i];
                pc.putc(ciphertext[i]);

            } else if (ciphertext2[i] == ciphertext3[i]) {
                ciphertext[i] = ciphertext2[i];
                pc.putc(ciphertext[i]);
            } else {
                // Default to plaintext1[i] if no majority (this is a fallback, can be customized)
                ciphertext[i] =ciphertext1[i];
                
            }
             
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            pc.putc(ciphertext[i]);         
         }
        
        printf("/n");


    }
}


It's really not clear what you're asking. Can you [edit] your question to clarify? What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Stack Overflow (SO) is a broad programming site. When you ask questions on specialized topics, do not use abbreviations that may be unfamiliar to most programmers without explaining them or citing sources. Set context for your question. Even if you are only looking for answers from experts in a particular field, questions need to be clear to future users, if for no other purpose than that they can see a question in some search results is not relevant to what they are looking for. Remember SO is intended to be a durable repository for future searches, so you should present quality questions.

Why would executing AES 3 times make it harder for an attacker? Where did you get the idea that this might be a good way of protecting the execution of AES? I'm intrigued.

@MaartenBodewes i am just trying to make the attack process take longer. can you recommend me some other simple countermeasures if not what im doing seems reasonable?

Your method would work maybe for fault injection attacks. But I don't see any advantages other than introducing a timeout for the attacker and some possible advantages on top of that. Generally we try and make the AES implementation itself less vulnerable against attack. In case of OpenSSL that means using the higher level EVP functionality most of the time, as that would likely result in usage of hardware AES implementations which are available on many x64 and ARM CPU's. Not sure about MbedTLS in that regard. On top of that, your timeout is CPU intensive.
